# Algorithm to compute partitions of a graph in N cliques

Tags: graphs, reference-request, clique

does anyone know of an efficient algorithm to compute the partition of a graph in N cliques?

Notice that N is the number of the cliques and not the size of them.

I have heard of the [2 cliques problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/two-clique-problem-check-graph-can-divided-two-cliques/), but I'm interested in the more general version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is known as [clique cover](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_cover) and it's NP-complete. In other words, no efficient algorithm is known.